# How to find $\sum_{r\ge 0} \binom{n}{r}\binom{n-r}{r} 2^{n-2r}$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions, combinatorial-proofs

Problem was to find $$\sum_{r\ge 0} \binom{n}{r}\binom{n-r}{r} 2^{n-2r}.$$ My partial progress i tried to motivate such that upper term in binomial terms gets constant rather than variable , so i thought of changing it to form $\binom{n}{n-r}\binom{n-r}{n-2r}$. Now it's of the form $\binom{n}{m}\binom{m}{k}$. We know it is equivalent to $\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{m-k}$. Doing this we get $\binom{n}{2r}\binom{2r}{r}2^{n-2r}$. Now what I need to do as next step as such still nothing the upper or lower terms r any constant values(sum to ) , all are variables still. Now by one answer by Robpratt i got by snake oil , is there any other way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Ty for the editing @ RobPratt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Algebraic proof of a combinatoric question (Combinatoric proof is given)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3396288/algebraic-proof-of-a-combinatoric-question-combinatoric-proof-is-given)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying
$$\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{m-k}=\binom{n}{m}\binom{m}{k}$$
with $m=2r$ and $k=r$, we have
$$\binom{n}{r}\binom{n-r}{r} = \binom{n}{2r}\binom{2r}{r}.$$
Now [snake oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Introducing_a_free_parameter_(snake_oil_method)) yields
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{r\ge 0} \binom{n}{r}\binom{n-r}{r} 2^{n-2r} z^n
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{r\ge 0} \binom{n}{2r}\binom{2r}{r} 2^{n-2r} z^n \\
&=\sum_{r\ge 0}\binom{2r}{r} 2^{-2r} \sum_{n\ge 2r} \binom{n}{2r} (2z)^n \\
&=\sum_{r\ge 0}\binom{2r}{r} 2^{-2r} \frac{(2z)^{2r}}{(1-2z)^{2r+1}} \\
&=\frac{1}{1-2z}\sum_{r\ge 0}\binom{2r}{r} \left[\left(\frac{z}{1-2z}\right)^2\right]^r \\
&=\frac{1}{1-2z}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4\left(\frac{z}{1-2z}\right)^2}} \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-2z)^2-4z^2}} \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}} \\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0} \binom{2n}{n}z^n.
\end{align}
So $$\sum_{r\ge 0} \binom{n}{r}\binom{n-r}{r} 2^{n-2r} = \binom{2n}{n}.$$

Comment: Whats the snake oil method Sir which converts the summation to double summation?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Introducing_a_free_parameter_(snake_oil_method)

Comment: Hmm sir how that converts into individual summation later can u tell?

Comment: [Newton's generalized binomial theorrem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem)

Comment: $$&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{r\ge 0} \binom{n}{2r}\binom{2r}{r} 2^{n-2r} z^n \\
&=\sum_{r\ge 0}\binom{2r}{r} 2^{-2r} \sum_{n\ge 2r} \binom{n}{2r} (2z)^n \\$$ i mean this Sir

Comment: That is still a double sum.  I interchanged the order of summation and pulled all the $r$-only parts out of the $n$ sum.

Comment: Ty got it now :)

Comment: I was always using this method or something similar for many years but I didn’t know it has a name i.e. snake oil. Sometimes, I studied them as a differential equation with the whole expression as a function of z.

Answer (score 2):

In seeking to evaluate

$$\sum_{r\ge 0} {n\choose r} {n-r\choose r} 2^{n-2r}$$

we write

$$\sum_{r\ge 0} {n\choose r} {n-r\choose n-2r} 2^{n-2r}
= 2^n [z^n] (1+z)^n
\sum_{r\ge 0} {n\choose r} 2^{-2r} \frac{z^{2r}}{(1+z)^r}
\\ = 2^n [z^n] (1+z)^n
\left(1+\frac{z^2}{4(1+z)}\right)^n
= \frac{1}{2^n} [z^n] (2+z)^{2n}
= {2n\choose n}$$

which is the desired closed form. Note that ${n-r\choose r}$ is not zero when $r\gt n$ while the coefficient extractor on ${n-r\choose n-2r}$ is. We nonetheless have equality because we get zero from ${n\choose r}$ on the extra range $r\gt n.$ Both forms are zero when $\lfloor n/2\rfloor \lt r \le n.$

Comment: $$\sum_{r\ge 0} {n\choose r} {n-r\choose n-2r} 2^{n-2r}
= 2^n [z^n] (1+z)^n how directly that is concluded next step ?

Comment: ${n-r\choose n-2r} = [z^{n-2r}] (1+z)^{n-r}.$

Comment: Nice approach ty Sir

Comment: @Marko Riedel can u write in detail how u got the second step from first? $$\sum_{r\ge 0} {n\choose r} {n-r\choose n-2r} 2^{n-2r}
= 2^n [z^n] (1+z)^n
\sum_{r\ge 0} {n\choose r} 2^{-2r} \frac{z^{2r}}{(1+z)^r}
\\$$

Comment: Just replace the binomial coefficient by the coefficient extractor as in the second comment. Note that $[z^{p-q}] f(z) = [z^p] z^q f(z).$

Comment: Its z^-q right Sir ? So how does it becomes z^q ?

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}\binom{n-r}{r}2^{n-2r}
&=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{2r}{r}\binom{n}{2r}2^{n-2r}\tag1\\
&=\frac{2^n}{2\pi}\sum_{r=0}^n\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^{2r}(x)\binom{n}{2r}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag2\\
&=\frac{2^n}{4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\left((1+\cos(x))^n+(1-\cos(x))^n\right)\mathrm{d}x\tag3\\
&=\frac{2^n}{4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\left(2^n\cos^{2n}(x/2)+2^n\sin^{2n}(x/2)\right)\mathrm{d}x\tag4\\
&=\frac{4^n}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^{2n}(x/2)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag5\\
&=\binom{2n}{n}\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $\binom{n}{r}\binom{n-r}{r}=\binom{2r}{r}\binom{n}{2r}$
$(2)$: $\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^{2r}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=4^{-r}\binom{2r}{r}$
$(3)$: $\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{2r}x^{2r}=\frac12\left((1+x)^n+(1-x)^n\right)$
$(4)$: $1+\cos(x)=2\cos^2(x/2)$ and $1-\cos(x)=2\sin^2(x/2)$
$(5)$: substitute $x\mapsto x+\pi$ in the $\sin^{2n}(x/2)$ integral
$(6)$: substitute $x\mapsto2x$ then
$\phantom{\text{(6):}}$ $\frac1{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\cos^{2n}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=4^{-n}\binom{2n}{n}$

Comment: Nice approach Sir

Comment: Thanks. I had just finished a couple of other problems using the integral of $\cos^{2n}(x)$, so I thought I'd try it here since $4^{-r}\binom{2r}{r}$ was there.

Answer (score 1):

For a combinatorial proof of
$$\sum_{r\ge 0} \binom{n}{r}\binom{n-r}{r} 2^{n-2r} = \binom{2n}{n},$$
first rewrite the LHS as
$$\sum_{r\ge 0} \binom{n}{2r}\binom{2r}{r} 2^{n-2r}$$ as in my other answer.  Both sides of the identity count the number of $n$-subsets of $\{1,\dots,2n\}$.  The RHS is clear.  For the LHS, condition on the number $r$ of "complementary" pairs $\{i,2n+1-i\}$ that appear in the $n$-subset.  Then there are $n-2r$ "singletons" where one element appears and $r$ complementary pairs where neither element appears.  This idea is explained in *Proofs That Really Count: The Art of Combinatorial Proof* (Identity 161).

Comment: Wym by number of n subsets from the set {1,2...n} Sir?

Comment: I had a typo, now corrected.  $\binom{2n}{n}$ counts the number of $n$-subsets of a $2n$-set.