# Proving $\sum_{k=0}^n {2n \choose 2k}{2k \choose k}2^{2n-2k} = {4n \choose 2n}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I'd like to prove that $\sum_{k=0}^n {2n \choose 2k}{2k \choose k}2^{2n-2k} = {4n \choose 2n}$. I'm not really sure where to start, maybe the identity ${2n \choose n}=\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}^2$ is relevant but applying it to the RHS doesn't seem to produce anything useful. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you familiar with double-counting arguments?

Comment: @J.G. Not really I'm afraid!

Comment: The idea is simply to count something in two different ways. In this case, you'll count something in a way that gives the RHS and in another way which gives the LHS. Typically, one of these ways is obvious (probably the RHS here) and the other way is a little contrived for the situation which works. Can you think of a way of doing this?

Comment: This identity appeared at the following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4135024/) where it was closed as a duplicate and additional links are provided.