# How to find a combinatorial proof for the following sum?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

I'm trying to find a combinatorial proof for the following sum:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^{2n-2k} \binom{2n}{2k} \binom{2k}{k} = \binom{4n}{2n}$$

I tried to ask and answer this question from both sides:
How many binary numbers of length 4n have exactly 2n zeros?

However, I'm having trouble answering this question for the left side.
I would appreciate any suggestion!

Comment: If $X$ is a set of size $2n,$ then $2^{2n-2k}\binom{2n}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}$ can be seen to count the number of tuples $(A,B,C)$ of disjoint subsets of  $X$ with $|A|=|B|=k.$ Not sure if that helps.

Comment: We can then treat $\binom{4n}{2n}$ as pairs of subsets (A,B)$ of $X$ with $|A|+|B|=2n.$

Comment: With some changes of variable, [How to find $\sum_{r\ge 0} \binom{n}{r}\binom{n-r}{r} 2^{n-2r}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4115260/how-to-find-sum-r-ge-0-binomnr-binomn-rr-2n-2r) is a duplicate also containing a combinatorial proof by RobPratt. Simply relabel $2n \to n$ and use the reasoning of Rob to obtain a proof.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3396288/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are $4n$ people total, consisting of $2n$ married couples. How many ways are there to choose a subset of exactly half of the people? Obviously, one answer to this question is $\binom{4n}{2n}$.

More specifically, for each $k\in \{0,1,\dots,n\}$, we can ask the number of ways to select $2n$ people such that exactly $2k$ couples are *together*, meaning they are either both chosen or both not chosen. The number of ways is exactly $2^{2n-2k}\binom{2n}{2k}\binom{2k}k$, so summing over $k$ leads to the left-hand-side.

Here is a more detailed proof, behind a spoiler block in case you want to try to find it yourself.

> The number of separated couples must be even, because $$2n=\text{#(separated couples)}+2\times\text{#(couples where both chosen)}$$ Since $\text{# (separated couples)}+\text{# (together couples)}=2n$, this further implies there must be an even number of together couples, justifying why are counting the number of ways to choose $2k$ together couples. 
>  
>   If there are $2k$ together couples, you can choose which couples are together in $\binom{2n}{2k}$ ways. 
>
>  Each separated couple has one chosen spouse and one non-chosen spouse. Therefore, the couples which are together must have an equal number of chosen and non-chosen people. This implies that exactly half of the together  couples are chosen. Therefore, there are $\binom{2k}k$ ways to choose which together couples are chosen.
>
>  Finally, for  each of the $2n-2k$ remaining separated couples, there are $2^{2n-2k}$ ways to select one spouse from each couple.

Comment: This is very nice.  But isn't it $2k$ *un*separated couples?

Comment: @BrianHopkins That was a mixup on my part, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a set of size $2n.$ Then $\binom{4n}{2n}$ can be seen to count the number of ordered pairs of (not necessarily disjoint) subsets of $X,$ $(A,B)$ with $|A|+|B|=2n.$ (This can be seen as counting subsets of $X\times\{1,2\}$ of size $2n,$ with $A$ corresponding to the elements of $X\times\{1\}$ and $B$ corresponding to $X\times\{2\}.$)"

On the other hand, $2^{2n-2k}\binom{2n}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}$ counts the number of ordered tuples $(A',B',C')$ of disjoint subsets with $|A'|=|B'|=k.$. So the sum counts tuples $(A',B',C')$ of disjoint subsets with $|A'|=|B'|.$

Now, $|B|=2n-|X\setminus B|,$ so if $(A,B)$ is in the first set, then $|A|=|B^c|,$ where $B^c=X\setminus B$ is the complement of $B.$

From $(A,B)$ we construct sets $(A',B',C')=(A\setminus B^c,B^c\setminus A, A\cap B^c).$ Show $|A'|=|B'|,$ and $A',B',C'$ are disjoint.

In reverse, given disjoint $(A',B',C'),$ with $|A'|=|B'|,$ we can find $A=A'\cup C',$ and $B=(B'\cup C')^c.$ Show $|A|+|B|=2n.$

Show these operations are inverses.

---

Example, when $n=2.$ We take $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $S=\{(1,1),(2,1),(4,1),(2,2)\}$ and map it to $A=\{1,2,4\}$ and $B=\{2\}.$

Then $B^c=\{1,3,4\}$ and so $A'=\{2\},B'=\{3\},$ and $C'=\{1,4\}.$

Answer (score 1):

$2n$ people were voting to go either to the beach or to the mountain. Each people was given two balls: one marked as first preference and the other marked as second preference, then they voted by dropping the balls into beach box and/or mountain box. Both boxes contained equal number of balls after the vote ended. How many possibilities are there?

**Right Hand Side**

$2n $ out of $4n$ balls went into the mountain box, the rest went into the beach box. Number of possibilities:

$$
\binom{4n}{2n}
$$

**Left Hand Side**

$2k$ out of $2n$ people put both of their balls into a box: $k$ people put both of their votes into mountain box, $k$ other people put both of their votes into beach box, the remaining $2n-2k$ people split their votes between the two boxes. Number of possibilities:

$$
2^{2n-2k}\binom{2n}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}
$$

If we sum for all possible $k$, we then end up with the total number of possibilities that the two boxes ended up containing equal number of balls.

**Conclusion**

Since both LHS and RHS count the same object, they must be equal:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}2^{2n-2k}\binom{2n}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}
=
\binom{4n}{2n}
$$